# Manually curry an add function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, currying

I am trying to create a type safe add function that is optionally curried

```
    const add:
      | ((x: number) => (y: number) => number)
      | ((x: number, y: number) => number) = (x: number, y?: number) => {
      if (y !== undefined) {
        return x + y;
      } else {
        return (y: number) => x + y;
      }
    };
```

I would like to be able to run this function with either

```
add(1, 5)
```

or

```
add(1)(5)
```

But currently the second invocation throws two type errors on compilation. The errors are

```
Type '(x: number, y?: number | undefined) => number | ((y: number) => number)' is not assignable to type '((x: number) => (y: number) => number) | ((x: number, y: number) => number)'.
  Type '(x: number, y?: number | undefined) => number | ((y: number) => number)' is not assignable to type '(x: number) => (y: number) => number'.
    Type 'number | ((y: number) => number)' is not assignable to type '(y: number) => number'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type '(y: number) => number'.
```

at the function definition and

```
Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
```

at the function invocation.

I have seen solutions to this problem that return an `any` type, but I've been unable to find a type safe solution. Is what I want to do currently possible with TypeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads), you can construct an `add()` function with this signature:

```
function add (x: number): (y: number) => number
function add (x: number, y: number): number
function add (x: number, y?: number): number | ((y: number) => number) {
    return y === undefined ? (y: number): number => x + y : x + y
}
```

The first two signatures indicate the valid calls, and the last signature is the unionized signature that encompasses both valid call signatures.

Comment: Thank you! I think that's exactly what I was looking for.